# Pedagogy for trustworthy versus untrustworthy news sources through free datasets

Tags: teaching, data, statistics

Teaching students to distinguish between trustworthy and untrustworthy sources of news has taken on an increased urgency recently, and the Chronicle of Higher Education recently described this as a higher education trend for 2017. Are there any freely available datasets on this issue that are amenable to the pedagogy of statistics?

In particular, I am looking for any dataset on trustworthy versus untrustworthy news sources, or on related issues, such as how the use of different media sources is associated with how well informed a person is. My goal is to integrate one or more datasets into undergraduate statistics courses in psychology, one course for 2nd year students and the other for 4th year. I'm certainly willing to simplify the data for teaching purposes if necessary.

Comment: Maybe your question fits better to http://opendata.stackexchange.com ...?!

Comment: What exactly should that dataset contain? Whether or not this is being taught at university, or are you looking for examples that could be used while teaching this topic?

Comment: There are _trustworthy_ sources of news?